# dynamically added checkboxes do not fire event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Using phonegap and javascript

I have a dynamically created UL list which two checkboxes. If I manually add the LI items then the click function works just fine.

But when I added my li items dynamically the click function does not fire.

```
//This is the code that I use to populate the UL list

if (records[r_key].name.indexOf("#") == -1) {
    $('#ItemSelection').append('<li><p class="name">' + records[r_key].name +'</p><input type="checkbox" id="w' + records[r_key].id +'" class="markedplayer"><input type="checkbox" id="s' + records[r_key].id + '" class="markedwinner"></li>');
}

//This is the code to do something when any box is checked
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    if (this.checked){
    //do something
    } else {
        //something else if not checked    
    } 
});
```

Comment: Use `on` instead. `click` doesn't work for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `on` and make a delegate event:

```
$("#ContainerID}").on('click', ':checkbox', function(){
```

Where `ContainerID` is the id of the static parent(Better be the closest as can be to the checkboxes)

It looks like in your case the container is `#ItemSelection`

Delegate events have the advantage to fire even on dynamic inserted elements.

Comment: This makes sense and aligns to other advice that I have read. But still nothing is happening. I replaced my click with $("#ItemSelection").on('click', ':checkbox', function(){ - you are correct itemselection is the UL id. I am still looking. I am sure it is probably somethings I am missing on my side. When I first tried to do on it did'nt compute and that was because I had an old version of jquery.

Comment: Okay go it - not sure what I missed, but it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to reattach the click even to the new items. The click event does not magically know you added anything new.

Listen for the click event on the ul and you do not have to worry about reattaching the event.

```
$("#ItemSelection").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){
    if (this.checked){
        //do something
    } else {
        //something else if not checked    
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That selector only fires once when the DOM is loaded. For it to work on each element added to the DOM you need to use the `on` method:

```
$(container).on('click', ':checkbox', function(){
    if (this.checked){
      //do something
    } else {
      //something else if not checked    
    }
});
```